# Getting an error when trying to read all rows of a recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba

I created a query separately and now want to use VBA to read its records and then send *certain* fields of *all* rows in an email.

I am currently stuck on trying to extract all the rows from the recordset. I know how to do it for one record, but not with a dynamic recordset. Every week, the recordset could potentially have 1-10 (approx.) records. I had hoped to do this by dynamically reading all rows, saving the fields that I want into variables, and then adding that to the email body, but I arrived at an error.

I'm getting an error that says: `Run-time error '3265': Item not found in this collection.`

Does anyone know how to fix this error and how I can put all resulting rows of the recordset into the email body?

**The code:**

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()

    'current_date variable instantiated in a module elsewhere
    current_date = Date

    'Using the Date function to run every Monday, regardless of the time of day
    If current_date = (Date - (DatePart("w", Date, 2, 1) - 1)) Then

        'MsgBox ("the current_date variable holds: " & current_date)

        Dim dbs As DAO.Database
        Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
        Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
        Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
        Dim varRecords As Variant
        Dim intNumReturned As Integer
        Dim intNumColumns As Integer
        Dim intColumn As Integer
        Dim intRow As Integer
        Dim strSQL As String
        Dim rst_jobnumber As String
        Dim rst_bfloc As String

        Set dbs = CurrentDb
        Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qry_BMBFLoc")
        Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset

        If rst.EOF Then

            MsgBox "Null."

        Else

            'Found this part of the code online and not sure if I'm using it right.
            varRecords = rst!GetRows(3)
            intNumReturned = UBound(varRecords, 2) + 1
            intNumColumns = UBound(varRecords, 1) + 1

            For intRow = 0 To intNumReturned - 1
              For intColumn = 0 To intNumColumns - 1
                 Debug.Print varRecords(intColumn, intRow)
              Next intColumn
            Next intRow
            'End of code found online.

            'rst.MoveFirst 'commenting this out because this query could potentially return multiple rows
            rst_jobnumber = rst!job & "-" & rst!suffix
            rst_bfloc = rst!Uf_BackflushLoc

            rst.Close
            dbs.Close

            Set rst = Nothing
            Set dbs = Nothing

            'Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
            'Dim oMail As MailItem

            'Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")

            'mail_body = "The following jobs do not have the special BF location set in Job Orders: " & rst_

            'Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            'oMail.Body = mail_body
            'oMail.Subject = "Blow Molding Jobs Missing BF Location"
            'oMail.To = "something@something.com" 'in the future, create a function that finds all of the SC users' emails from their Windows user
            'oMail.Send

            'Set oMail = Nothing
            'Set oApp = Nothing

        End If

    End If

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error #: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: What line? Can you step thru until it highlights offending line?

Comment: Add a debug line on `intNumReturned = UBound(varRecords, 2) + 1` and add a watch on `varRecords` - see if it's actually an array

Comment: @dbmitch the offending line is `varRecords = rst!GetRows(3)`. This is reasonably incorrect because it's not dynamically using the number of rows in the resulting query, which recently changed to 6 rows.

Comment: Updated answer - you're not using dot operator

Comment: I don't think GetRows is what your really after here is it? You always grab 3 rows regardless of the number returned in the recordset?

Comment: @random_answer_guy yea no it's not. I put it there to tinker around with it. I really want to grab all records from the recordset and put it into the email body.

Comment: It "appears" your looking for varRecords = rst.recordcount, to find your number of records that you need to iterate...

Comment: Hmm interesting, I'll test it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try working with this code and see how it works for you. I was unsure if you were sending one email per or one email listing all (I assumed the latter)

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim strMessageBody As String

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qry_BMBFLoc")

strMessageBody = "The following jobs do not have the special BF location set in Job Orders: "

If Not (rst.EOF And rst.BOF) Then
    rst.MoveFirst
    Do Until rst.EOF = True           
          strMessageBody = strMessageBody & rst!job & "-" & rst!suffix & ","
    rst.MoveNext
    Loop

  If Right(strMessageBody, 1) = "," Then strMessageBody = Left(strMessageBody, Len(strMessageBody)-1)
  End If
  rst.Close

Set rst = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing
```

Comment: This worked nicely, but would you have any tips on how to make the output string into a list? The output that I get in the email is `The following jobs do not have the special BF location set in Job Orders: BM00001610-27BM00001608-27BM00001633-27BM0001608A-27BM00001612-27BM00001634-27`. It looks very messy...

Comment: Nevermind, got it. Just had to use `vbCrLf`. Thank you so much for your time and patience!!!

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT - not using dot operator

Replace

```
varRecords = rst!GetRows(3)
```

with

```
varRecords = rst.GetRows(3)
```

Do you have three rows in your recordset?

If not `rst!GetRows(3)` will return false - and then next line will fail when you try to use UBound.

[A good example of how to implement GetRows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194427.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Another possibility is if you're trying to access a Field that's not in your recordset on a line that has `rst!`